# Duplicate header "Mime-Version" error, sending e-mail with Plone Mail adapter

Tags: email, smtp, plone, postfix-mta, ploneformgen

I have a problem sending e-mails with a Plone mail adapter using Amazon's "Simple" Email Service as an SMTP server. This is the error message I get in the mail log on my Postfix server using Amazon as a relay:

> Duplicate header 'MIME-Version'.

The mail adapter puts an extra Mime-Version in the mail header before sending it. On the SMTP server i used prior to Amazon, the mails went through, and I can see on the mails from earlier that there is a duplicate Mime-Version field.

How can i change this in Plones Mail adapter so it doesn't add it twice?

I know it's not Postfix fault, because other mails from Plone, not using the Mail Adapter, get through with no problem

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this as well.

```
vim /opt/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7.1-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/content/formMailerAdapter.py
```

Line 858 I did a quick modification to comment out this:

```
# headerinfo['MIME-Version'] = '1.0'
```

I'm not sure of the consequences of doing so as of yet though, but the duplicate header is removed.

Comment: Seems a good fix, as the MIME-Version is already set automatically elsewhere.  I have fixed it in the code (to be released as 1.7.3): https://github.com/smcmahon/Products.PloneFormGen/commit/bb1e035f2fa7299ab8d51963d7d09fc999999d56

Comment: I have just backported this to 1.6.8 and made a release.